# Creating Tables with Python and SQLite, no such table

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm using Python to create a table through SQLite3, I'm getting told the table has been created in the interpreter but when looking at the table in cmd, there's no such table. Here's my code:

```
import sqlite3 as db

conn = db.connect('test.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("create table films(title text, year text, director text)")
print("tables added")
```

In the interpreter I get:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
tables added
```

But when viewing the database through SQLite in cmd I get told:

```
Error: no such table: films
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you run the script and interpreter in **the same directory**. Otherwise they referenece two different db files.

Answer (score 0):

Your code just works :-) I guess there's something wrong on how you're trying to access your table:

```
sucre:~ rlucia$ python sqltable.py
tables added
sucre:~ rlucia$ sqlite3 test.db
SQLite version 3.8.0.2 2013-09-03 17:11:13
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> PRAGMA table_info([films]);
0|title|text|0||0
1|year|text|0||0
2|director|text|0||0
sqlite> ^D
sucre:~ rlucia$
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing conn.commit(). Therefore your new table isn't saved and the SQL viewer cannot find the table.